# Pass xargs argument as a string to another command with '>'?

Tags: find, io-redirection, xargs

Suppose I have a bunch of files in `/tmp/`.

I do

```
find . -type f | xargs -iFILES
```

And I want to do a `md5sum` in each file, outputting to a file with the same name, but with `.md5` extension.

```
find . -type f | xargs -iFILES md5sum FILES > FILES.md5
```

This is supposed to create a md5 file for each file found by find command. Instead, it creates a single FILES.md5 file on disk with checksums from all files.

How do I say to md5sum command that the FILES represent the current filename and not a FILES literal string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some way to say that you want to send the output of `md5sum` to a file. Since `find` (or `xargs`) doesn't have this functionality built-in, and `md5sum` only knows how to print to standard output, a shell redirection is the most straightforward way.

Note that your command won't work in the general case for another reason: the output format of `find` is not the input format of `xargs`, they differ with file names containing whitespace or `\"'`. Use `find -exec` instead.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'md5sum "$0" >"$0.md5"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use a subshell to handle the IO redirection:

```
find . -type f | xargs -iFILES sh -c 'md5sum FILES > FILES.md5'
```

Answer (score 5):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
find . -type f | parallel md5sum {} \> {}.md5
```

You get the added benefit of running md5sum in parallel and that files like:

```
My brother's 12" records.txt
```

will not cause your command to crash. Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ